# How do you access newly appended HTML elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here's an example of my problem:

**HTML**

```
<p><a class="clickme" href="#">I would like to say:</a></p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("a.clickme").click(function() {
    $('p').append('<div><a href="#" id="say-hello">Hello</a></div>');
});

$("#say-hello").click(function(){
    alert('test hello');
});
```

Here's a fiddle with the example code:
http://jsfiddle.net/johnmorris/2UVYd/2/

The first click function fires just fine. But, the alert (or any other function) will not fire on the newly appended elements. I basically understand that the appended element didn't exist on page load, so jQuery doesn't "see" it... thus, the second click function not firing.

I'm just wondering if there's a way around that. And, if so, what is it. I can't seem to get this figured out.

Comment: One other thing to be cognizant of: if clicked multiple times, your `a` is appending multiple elements with the same `id`.  This is against the HTML spec, as `id`s are supposed to be unique within a document.  I would suggest using `class` instead.

Comment: Thanks! My actual code does append a class. I posted the example, because my actual code is uber-long and convoluted. But, I have thought of that. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait to assign the event until the element exists:

```
$("a.clickme").click(function() {
    $('p').append('<div><a href="#" id="say-hello">Hello</a></div>');
    $("#say-hello").click(function(){
        alert('test hello');
    });
});
```

Notice that the `click` assignment for the newly created anchor is INSIDE the other `click` callback.

@Vega is using another technique called "delegation" where you assign the click for "say-hello" to the `p` instead of the anchor itself.  When the anchor is clicked the event "bubbles" up through the DOM and is gets caught by the event listener on the `p` tag.  This works correctly, but this may not be the right time for delegation.  Delegation is usually used when you have a collection of items inside of a common container (e.g. LIs in a UL) that all have to handle the same event.  If you just have one "say-hello" then I would recommend not using delegation.
​

If you need to be able to click the button multiple times and have it inserted multiple times then delegation might be the right option (but you'll need to stop using a hard-coded ID). Or... you could do it this way:

```
$("a.clickme").click(function() {
    $('<div><a href="#" class="say-hello">Hello</a></div>').find('.say-hello')
            .click(function(){
                alert('test hello');
            })
        .end()
        .appendTo('p');
});
```

This code actually digs into the newly created elements and attaches the event before appending to the DOM. (Oh, and notice that I'm using a className rather than an id for "say-hello".)

Comment: This worked for me. Actually, all of them "worked" but this is what I went with. Thanks for the help! You guys are freakin' awesome! :)

Answer (score 6):

Your code doesn't work because `$("#say-hello")` doesn't exist in dom when you bind it to click handler.

However you can use `.on` like in below syntax which will look for element with ID `say-hello` that will be later added to 'p',

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2UVYd/4/)

```
  $("p").on('click', '#say-hello', function(){
    alert('test hello');
  })
```

Comment: Depending on the use case, delegation might be the wrong choice. No need to delegate if there is only one element...

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with @Prestaul code, but yours worked just fine, as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this, which avoids the issue of creating multiple DOM elements with the same ID.  It gives each a random ID by appending a random number between 1 and 100 to the ID name:

```
<script>
    $("a.clickme").click(function() {
        var newId = "say-hello" + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
        $('p').append('<div><a href="#" id="' + newId +'">Hello</a></div>');

        $("#"+newId).click(function(){
            alert('test hello');
        })
    });

</script>
```

Note that I placed the addition of a click handler within the existing `<a>` click.

Randoms don't guarantee no conflict, but make the range big enough and it can be a safe assumption.  Or just use a counter to ensure there's not ID conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I may end up using the random number idea, but for now the code by @Prestaul seemed to work best. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".your_append_element_class").live('click',function() {
    // Your Code goes here..
});
```

Comment: [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated and has been removed in jQuery 1.9. Use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.