# Cannot reference css class in jquery dynamically added html table rows

Tags: css, jquery-ui

In jQuery, I created an HTML table dynamically and at the end, I add a click function to add a class from a loaded external css file.  In the Chrome javascript console, I can see the class added correctly but the style (colors) do not change. It's like the stylesheet elements do not exist.  I added a body style change just to prove it is in fact loading with the HTML page.

Here is the js function that creates the table:

```
function processGetCallback(data) {
var tableText;
$('#KenTest').empty();
    tableText = "<table cellpadding=2><tr><th>ID</th><th>text</th><th>date</th></tr>";
    $.each(data, function(i, DataRow) {
        tableText = tableText.concat("<tr><td>" + DataRow.IDCol + "</td><td>" + DataRow.txtCol + "</td><td>" + DataRow.dtCol + "</td></tr>");
    });
    tableText = tableText.concat("</table>");
    $('#KenTest').append(tableText);
    $('#KenTest tr').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("hightlight");
    });
}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
background-color: lightgray;
}

td.highlight {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

tr.highlight {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

li.highlight {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
```

And here is the HTML page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test of jQuery Ajax</title>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery Ajax Test</h1>

<h2>Get Ken Test Data</h2>
<ul id="KenTest">
<li class="highlight">ID: 1, txtCol: xyz, dtCol:1/1/2015</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<button id="btnGetAll" onclick="CallGetAllAjax()">Get All Rows</button><button id="btnGet2" onclick="CallGetTwoAjax()">Get 2 Rows</button>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js\main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(this).addClass("hightlight"); => $(this).addClass("highlight");` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the elements to which you are binding the click event handler does not exist in DOM when the handler is registered.

Here's a similar question, and there's a good solution from Prestaul: [How do you access newly appended HTML elements in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145727/how-do-you-access-newly-appended-html-elements-in-jquery)

Comment: that is a good practice but was not the issue in this case.  My fat fingers caused this issue.  BTW, I think I am ok in the code as I am assigning the click handler to the "this" object as the element is created.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `click` method in its *delegated* form.

You may rather use the `.on()` method like

```
$('#KenTest').on("click", "tr", function () {
    $(this).addClass("hightlight");
});
```

Comment: Thank you JFK, I think I did try that in one of my many iterations before finally seeing my typo that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how long I stared at this and kept missing the typo :/ The js had the class named "hightlight" and the css had the class named "highlight". Doh!